# Apollo GraphQL "writeQuery" causing re-render to the app which is leading to an unnecessary network request

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

I'm working on a chat app, developed using Apollo GraphQL and React and I have the following issue:

I have a component called "Conversation" which is fetching an array of messages between two users (the logged-in user and other user) using the "useQuery" hook of Apollo which is invoked every time the component mounts.

When a new message is sent by the logged-in user, I'm updating the cached array of messages using the "writeQuery" function provided by Apollo.

By doing that, the "Conversation" component is getting re-rendered, which is leading to an unnecessary network request because the "useQuery" hook is triggered again.

I would love to hear if there is a way of preventing "writeQuery" from triggering a re-render to the relevant component.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: bad structure/fetch policy/effects/props? ... show code, don't describe it ... writeQuery is for forcing rerendering (to update view) but shouldn't make a request

Comment: But because of the re-rendering, the "useQuery" is getting invoked again, which is leading to an unnecessary network request.

Comment: not true ... if properly implemented ... again, more context/show code/components structure